# Which Exception to throw when 1 parameter has an illegal value based on a 2nd parameter

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that takes 2 `boolean` parameters. If the first parameter is true, the 2nd parameter can not also be true.

If they are both true I want to throw an `Exception`, but I am not sure which exception is the most accurate.

Example:

```
public void addEvent(boolean hadPositiveResult, boolean needsFurtherStudy) {
    if (hadPositiveResult && needsFurtherStudy)
        throw new Exception("Can not need further study if the event had a positive result"); //this should be a more specific exception

    //rest of method code omitted...
}
```

Would `IllegalArgumentException` or `IllegalStateException` make sense? Is there a better one that describes it better?

Comment: **off-topic: opinion based** - *my opinion neither; it sounds like an expected case which by definition is **not an exceptional** case*.

Comment: You want your code to raise an exception based on the values of the arguments to your method, rather than the state of the object on which the method operates. That sure sounds like it's an `IllegalArgumentException`. But the compiler won't complain even if you throw a `NullPointerException` so it's basically up to you.

Comment: You can try `SecondParameterIllegalException` ;-)

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Should that be a subclass of IllegalStateException or IllegalArgumentException?

Answer (score 3):

Consider not doing it that way. Don't get into the "I need a bunch of flags on my methods" game.

You see, good interfaces make it **hard** for your client code to do the wrong thing! In your case, one "gets it wrong" by simply passing (true, true). That sounds awfully easy to get wrong. Especially as your method name doesn't indicate **at all** that `addEvent(true, true)` will throw up at runtime. Honestly: that is in no way a robust design!

One potential solution: use an enum instead of a boolean. That enum contains only constants for **valid** cases. But honestly, having something like

```
enum AdderConditions {
   NONE, NEEDS_POSITIVE_RESULT, NEEDS_FURTHER_STUDY };
```

isn't too appealing either.

In order to really "resolve" this, it would be necessary to understand your requirements in detail; and probably design a completely different solution; but that is something beyond the scope of this site.

So, my personal recommendation: find somebody around you who is really experienced in doing good OO designs; show him your problem and ask how he would restructure your whole flow to avoid getting into the "setting flags" business completely! I guarantee you: it will be worth it.

Sooner or later, you might have "other" flags somewhere, and then you end up with client code doing "true, false, true", and so on; and nobody understands what that is doing, or why the one combination works; and the other gives you exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
> inappropriate argument.

So yes, it sounds like throwing an IllegalArgumentException would be appropriate.  Additionally you can add a message to the exception to inform the caller of the error, e.g.

```
if (param1 && param2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both parameters cannot be true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can throw `IllegalArgumentException`, but inside message you can say what was wrong with the parameters, for example:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("second parameter....");
```

Then you can get the message in the `catch` clause and check what was wrong.